# policy base design: conditionally change a member variable from policy class

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

My program defines an `Animal` struct that can be configured with `CanSwim/CanNotSwim` and `CanBark/CanNotBark`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct CanSwim {
};

struct CanNotSwim {
};

struct CanBark {
    CanBark() : volume(10) {}
    void bark() {
        std::cout << "bark at volume " << volume << std::endl;
    }

    void setVolume(int newVolume) {
        volume = newVolume;
    }

private:
    int volume;
};

struct CanNotBark {
};

template<class SwimType, class BarkType>
struct Animal : public SwimType, public BarkType {
    Animal() = default;
};

int main() {
    auto dog = Animal<CanSwim, CanBark>();
    dog.bark();

    auto cat = Animal<CanNotSwim, CanBark>();
    cat.bark();

    return 0;
}
```

Now how do I set a rule to automatically double `CanBark::volume` when an `Animal` is configured with class `CanNotSwim` (in compilation time)? To have:

```
    auto dog = Animal<CanSwim, CanBark>();
    dog.bark();
    // "bark at volume 10"

    auto cat = Animal<CanNotSwim, CanBark>();
    cat.bark();
    // "bark at volume 20"
```

I don't intend to move function `bark()` from `CanBark` to `Animal`.

Comment: A staple of policy based design is that the policies are orthogonal. If you introduce such dependencies the orthogonality doesn't stand. Consider thinking more deeply about your policies if this situation occurs.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica For my design, most policies are orthogonal, a few of them are correlated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CRTP, you might got that information:

```
struct CanSwim {};
struct CanNotSwim {};

template <typename Der>
struct CanBark {
    CanBark() : volume(std::is_base_of_v<CanNotSwim, Der> ? 20 : 10) {}
    void bark() {
        std::cout << "bark at volume " << volume << std::endl;
    }

    void setVolume(int newVolume) { volume = newVolume; }

private:
    int volume;
};

template <typename Der>
struct CanNotBark {};

template<class SwimType, template <typename> class BarkType>
struct Animal : public SwimType, public BarkType<Animal<SwimType, BarkType>> {
    Animal() = default;
};

int main() {
    auto dog = Animal<CanSwim, CanBark>();
    dog.bark();

    auto cat = Animal<CanNotSwim, CanBark>();
    cat.bark();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba1891f49bfbcae7)

As alternative, you might provide the information in constructor:

```
struct CanSwim {};
struct CanNotSwim {};

struct CanBark {
    CanBark(bool canSwim) : volume(canSwim ? 10 : 20) {}
    void bark() {
        std::cout << "bark at volume " << volume << std::endl;
    }

    void setVolume(int newVolume) { volume = newVolume; }

private:
    int volume;
};


struct CanNotBark {
    CanNotBark(bool canSwim) {}
};

template<class SwimType, class BarkType>
struct Animal : public SwimType, public BarkType {
    Animal() : BarkType(std::is_same_v<SwimType, CanSwim>) {}
};

int main() {
    auto dog = Animal<CanSwim, CanBark>();
    dog.bark();

    auto cat = Animal<CanNotSwim, CanBark>();
    cat.bark();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4353baadaed526ee)

Comment: Is possible to do it with the original inheritance structure? `struct Animal : public SwimType, public BarkType<Animal<SwimType, BarkType>>` looks a bit tangled to me.

Comment: There is a proposal [deducing this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0847r0.html#crtp-without-the-c-r-or-even-t) which would allow simpler syntax.

Comment: @Rahn it's necessary for **this solution**. maybe you should make all policy to be CRTP template.

Comment: Added another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Uhmmm... what about simply modify the `Animal` constructor to call the `setVolume()` (in case `BarkType` is `CanBark`) with the correct value?

I mean... something as

```
template<class SwimType, class BarkType>
struct Animal : public SwimType, public BarkType {
    Animal ()
    {
       if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<BarkType, CanBark> )
          BarkType::setVolume(std::is_same_v<SwimType, CanNotSwim> ? 20 : 10);
    }
};
```

This obviously require at least C++17 (`if constexpr` is introduced in C++17) or the `setVolume()` call gives and error in the `CanNotBark` case. Before C++17 you have to use SFINAE to activate/disactivate two different constructors.

Otherwise, if you need that the correct volume value directly inside `CanBark` at the construction moment, you have to pass the information as template parameter, as showed in the Jarod42's answer.